# C++ Logical AND Operator

Tags: c++, operators, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I am trying to use the logical AND operator, but am getting some an unexpected behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  unsigned flags = 0;
  cout << "flags = " << flags << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    flags &= (1 << i);
    cout << "Anding with " << (1 << i) << endl;
    cout << "flags = " << flags << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
flags = 0
Anding with 1
flags = 0
Anding with 2
flags = 0
Anding with 4
flags = 0
```

Expected output:

```
flags = 0
Anding with 1
flags = 1
Anding with 2
flags = 3
Anding with 4
flags = 7
```

Note that I can get the expected output by simply replacing & with + in my program. But I wanted to know what is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `&` is the *bitwise*, not logical, "and" operator. Also, based on your expected output, it seems you want the bitwise "*or*" (`|`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common mistake with bitwise and... people assume `a & b` means "return all the bits of `a` combined with all the bits of `b`... it doesn't. It means "return the bits that are set in *both* `a` *and* `b`".

If a is 1, and b is 2, the binary representations are `01` and `10`... no bits in common! The result will of course be 0.

What you need to be using is bitwise *or*. `a | b` means "return all the bits that are set in *either* `a` *or* `b`.

If a is 1, and b is 2, the binary representations are `01` and `10`, and so the result is `11` or the 3 you expected.

It may help to think of these operations as the set operations "*intersection*" and "*union*", rather than the binary operations "*and*" and "*or*".

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up `|` and `&`. Your expected result corresponds to the iteration of:

```
 flags |= (1 << i);
```

The bitwise OR in `|=` will "add" bits to your bitset `flags`, whereas the bitwise AND can only remove bits.